# Oracle sorting with functions manipulation

Tags: oracle, sorting, plsql

Why oracle is not sorting this correctly or what i'm missing?

```
select a from (
    select '100##' as a from dual union 
    select '43##Y' as a from dual union 
    select '58##Y' as a from dual union 
    select '78##' as a from dual union 
    select '##' as a from dual union 
    select '##' as a from dual
) order by to_number(substr(a, 0, instr(a, '#') - 1)) asc;
```

**Output :**

```
43##Y
58##Y
78##
100##
##
```

Comment: What are you expecting - why is it incorrect? Are you expecting the `##` to come first; or is the problem just that there is only one `##` in the result? The latter is nothing to do with the sorting - you'd only see one if you had no order-by clause too, because you have `union` rather than `union all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace 0 with 1 in `substr` start position as index starts from 1 in oracle.

```
select a from (
    select '100##' as a from dual union 
    select '43##Y' as a from dual union 
    select '58##Y' as a from dual union 
    select '78##' as a from dual union 
    select '##' as a from dual union 
    select '##' as a from dual
) order by to_number(substr(a, 1, instr(a, '#') - 1)) asc;
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=54e7af1c58aa4728a87357436fde52f3)

Comment: Your fiddle still has zero in the order-by; but it doesn't affect the result. Despite the docs saying it should be non-zero, zero is treated the same as one. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e2a4790bf92dee131a220bcae596d012)

Answer (score 0):

Popeye said all right, I wanted to mention one more thing:
If you use union between same values it will return only one of them as sorted result,

```
.
.
.    
select '##' as a from dual union
select '##' as a from dual
.
.
.
```

But if you use union all as bellow it will duplicate them all.

```
.
.
.    
select '##' as a from dual union all
select '##' as a from dual
.
.
.
```

Thanks.